# Bring back the Progress Monitor dialog after click on "run in background"

Tags: java, jobs, progressmonitor

I have a user Job like this:

```
    Job job = new Job("bla1") {

                @Override
                protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                    monitor.beginTask("Dummy 2", 100);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                        if (monitor.isCanceled()) {
                            return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
                        }
                        System.out.println(i);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        monitor.worked(1);
                    }
                    monitor.done();
                    return Status.OK_STATUS;
                }

            };

            job.setUser(true);
            job.schedule();
```

When this Job starts, I got a progress dialog with 3 buttons: Run in background, Cancel and Details, showing the progress of the job. This is also shown on the status bar.
If I press "Run in background", the dialog is hidden but you still see the progress on status bar. If I want to cancel the job, I can not anymore because the dialog can not be shown again even if I press the small button from status bar (Shows background operations in Progress View).

I would be glad if someone could help me :).